# Reading from a html form object in javascript only if object exists

Tags: javascript

post submit I want to javascript/client side read user input

```
var h = document.getElementById("myTEXTbox").value;
```

but the textbox only exists depending earlier user choices. is the an if object exists in javascript?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myTEXTbox"),
    h = element ? element.value : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

check the return of `getEelementById`, if an element doesnt exist it will return null, and since it is a falsey value you can use it in a if statement.

```
var element = document.getElementById("myTEXTbox");
var h =  element ? element.value : "";
```

So if `element` is not `null`, `h` will be set to `element.value` otherwise it will be set to an empty string

Answer (score 1):

If the object exists then it is an object, if not, it will return undefined!

So you can test it like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myTEXTbox"),
    h = (element)? element.value : '';
```

Basically, you are using this logic: If the element does exist "`(element)`" or alternatively `(el!=undefined)` then read the value, if not set the value of `'h'` to `''` (empty). This could be null or another value.